# Expand and Collapse tableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hey i am newbie in ios development. I want to expand and collapse tableview, so my code for doing it is:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (indexPath.section != 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
        }
        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar )
            {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:1]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
    }
}
```

and my minimize row method like as

```
-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{

for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
    NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
    NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
    if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
        [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
    }

    if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
        [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        [self.tblLeft deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:1]]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }
}
}
```

From this method and coding I achieved the `Expand and Collapse` tableViewCell, this works. As It expands tableViewCell on click and collapses it when second time click on Expandable cell.

But I want to work as such: On clicking of any expandable cell, **other** expandable cell will be collapse automatically.

Can any one help me for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last cell that was expandable to collapse after when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

After your `@interface` put:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
```

Now you can use it in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Collapse the last cell expanded
    if (indexPath.section != 0) {
        if(self.lastIndexPath) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath];
            NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:self.lastIndexPath.row];
            if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
                NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];            
            }    [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        }
    }

    // Save the current indexPath as the last one expanded
    self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

    // This is your current code - I didn't change it
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
        }
        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar )
            {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:1]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the code need some ajustments, but see if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples available for expand and collapse table.

You can refer below example

http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Answer (score 0):

You surly can expand and collaps cells easily by using [HVTableView](http://github.com/innovian/HVTableView)

> This is a subclass of UITableView with expand/collapse feature that
>   comes useful in many scenarios.