# How to create a multilevel UITableView upto n level in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create a generic `UITableView` expand and collapse so that it can be bind with array of arrays/dictionary to multilevel.

Number of levels will be defined on run time. Please help, I am working in Objective-C.

Comment: You can't do that.  iOS doesn't have `NSOutlineView` like Cocoa.

Comment: Try this. Worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165679/expand-and-collapse-tableview-cell

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Worked for me as per my requirement.

------ To expand the rows ------

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    
    NSDictionary * d = [self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray * ar = [d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        BOOL isAlreadyInserted = NO;
        
        for(NSDictionary * dInner in ar){
            NSInteger index = [self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted = (index > 0 && index != NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
        }
        
        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        }
        else {
            NSUInteger count = indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray * arCells = [NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary * dInner in ar) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            
            [tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [tableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
}
```

------ To minimize the rows ------

```
-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray *)ar{
    for(NSDictionary * dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove = [self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        
        NSArray * arInner = [dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count] > 0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }
        
        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner] != NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            
            [self.mainTableView beginUpdates];
            [self.mainTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.mainTableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After some changes according to my UITableView, this is working fine. Thanks a lot.